# VisualBasic script : How to replace character at certain index in string?

Tags: vbscript

Consider the following script

```
For i=1 To Len(str)
ascOfChar = Asc(Mid(str,i,1))  - 1
newChar = Chr(ascOfChar)
Mid(str,i,1) = newChar
```

I want to replace every character in string "str" with it's previous one.

I get the newChar correctly but how do I replace each char from "str" with its newChar knowing the char index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the `Mid` function

```
variable = Mid( string, start, length )
```

AND the `Mid` instruction

```
Mid( target, start, length ) = string
```

The `Mid` instruction (not function) is included in the list of elements in VB/VBA not included in VBS. So, you can not use it.

This is a similar solution to your code, but concatenation is used to generate the ouput string.

```
Option Explicit

    Dim str, output, i, newAsc

    str="This is a test 98765"
    output=""

    For i=1 To Len(str)
        newAsc = AscW(Mid(str,i,1))-1
        If newAsc < 0 Then 
            newAsc = 65535
        End If
        output = output & ChrW(newAsc)
    Next 

    WScript.Echo str
    WScript.Echo output
```