# How to capitalise a random letter?

Tags: vbscript

In VBScript is it possible to select a random letter and capitalize it until all letters have been capitalized at least once?

```
Dim a
a = "Hello"

For i=o To Len(a)-1
    If Mid(a,i+1, 1) = Mid(a, i+1, 1) Then
        b = Mid(a, i+1, 1)
        MsgBox b
    End If
Next
```

That's some code I gathered. So far it reads a string letter by letter.
I want the output to be something like:

```
hello
Hello
hEllo
etc.
```

but I can't see how to do it without getting into super complex `Mid` `Left` `Right` statements that become confusing. Is it possible? Or do I need to use something like `Mid(LCase(s,1,1) & Mid(UCase(s,2,1)) & Mid(LCase(s,3,3)`?

Comment: You are on the right track, but you need to look at using the `Randomize()` and `Rnd()` functions to provide a random seed and random value for use in the loop.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generating Random Numbers and Letters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43598625/generating-random-numbers-and-letters)

Comment: The loop should be used to determine how many capitialised values should be added to the string. Start by using `Randomize()` to set a random seed *(run this outside the loop only once)* then inside the loop use `Rnd()` to generate a position value. Here is an example of [Replacing a character at a certain character position in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24884498/692942).

Answer (score 1):

Use `Len()` to determine the positions of letters to capitalize and `Left() + UCase(Mid()) + Mid()` to actually uppercase the letter at p =

```
Option Explicit
Dim s : s = "hello"
Dim l : l = Len(s)
Dim i : i = 0
Do Until s = UCase(s)
   Dim p : p = Fix(Rnd() * l) + 1
   If Mid(s, p, 1) <> UCase(Mid(s, p, 1)) Then s = Left(s, p - 1) & UCase(Mid(s, p, 1)) & Mid(s, p + 1)
   WScript.Echo i, p, s
   i = i + 1
Loop
```

output:

```
cscript 52911013.vbs
0 4 helLo
1 3 heLLo
2 3 heLLo
3 2 hELLo
4 2 hELLo
5 4 hELLo
6 1 HELLo
7 4 HELLo
8 5 HELLO
```

Comment: tahnks, but the problem is that ignores many of the possibilities such as HellO, HelLo ect, sorry to be such a bother but thank you for your help regardless.